# Uploading file to linux server in java

Tags: java, file

I have to create a web application in java to upload all types of file.War file will be deployed on the linux server.The problem is path.Everything is working on localhost but when it deployed to linux server its not working,the page became empty.The below is my code:

```
try {

            dbConnectionUtils db = new dbConnectionUtils();

            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = db.getConnection();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(upload_images.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(upload_images.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            Map<String, String> paramMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            InputStream filecontent = null;
            FileItem modelFile = null;
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            // Set overall request size constraint
            upload.setSizeMax(50 * 1024 * 1024);

            // Parse the request
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            // List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new
            // DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(req);
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    // Process regular form field (input
                    // type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                    // ... (do your job here)
                    //                    System.out.println("TESTING " + fieldname + " : "
                    //                            + fieldvalue);
                    paramMap.put(fieldname, fieldvalue);
                } else {
                    // Process form file field (input type="file").
                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                    modelFile = item;
                    System.out.println("ModelFile"+modelFile);
                    filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                    // ... (do your job here)
                    //                    System.out.println("TESTING *****" + fieldname + " : "
                    //                            + filename + " : " + item.getName());
                    paramMap.put(fieldname, filename);
                }
            }
 System.out.println("filemanager");
            String filemanager = paramMap.get("filemanager");
            if ((filemanager != null) && (filemanager.equalsIgnoreCase("Submit"))) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Inside");
                    String filename = paramMap.get("filename");
                    String file = paramMap.get("file");
                    System.out.println("........." + file);
                    String prj = paramMap.get("PjList");

                    if (null != filename && null != file) {

                        String relative = getRealpath() + "filemanager\\" + request.getSession(true).getAttribute("logged_user_id") + "\\";


                        File mkTime = new File(relative);
                        mkTime.mkdirs();
                        String ipath = uploadData(modelFile, relative);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ipath);
                        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                        // Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
                        LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

                        //create a new large object
                        int oid = lobj.create(LargeObjectManager.READ | LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

                        //open the large object for write
                        LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.WRITE);
                        byte buf[] = new byte[2048];
                        int s, tl = 0;
                        while ((s = fis.read(buf, 0, 2048)) > 0) {
                            obj.write(buf, 0, s);
                            tl += s;
                        }
                        // Close the large object
                        obj.close();
int f=8;
                        String fileType = modelFile.getContentType();
}
```

Comment: Any exception? My guess is you are using the wrong file separator when defining `relative` local variable

Comment: I have uploaded war file to linux server,after that i cant able to see any log or exception.i can check only with local host.I have to set path to upload file in linux server.I have tried                                                                String path ="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/QuartzBee/filemanager"; but its not worked

Comment: Note that the specification for web applications (WAR deployments) does not allow you to use the file system.  If you choose to do so anyway, your code is vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

does the user/owner on the hosting server have permissions to write to the folders/create a subfolder in the PWD you are running your WAR from? CHMOD 777 your WARs folder and see if it lets you create the relative subdir needed  to run.

If that is not the case the reason you are not seeing an error is you only defined ClassNotFoundException and SQLException errors and not a more general error catch to report the access issues that I think you might be having.

Put a generic error catch around your try{} and print the error, I think you'll get some sort of access error.

Comment: I have set 777 permissions already eventhough its not working.How to print exception in web application..

Comment: catch and system.out.println, should appear as paintext on your blank page

Answer (score 0):

You should always use "/" as path separators in Java.

"\" only works on Windows.